# Let $E$ be uniformly convex and $\varphi$ proper convex l.s.c. Then $\inf _{y \in E}\{|x-y|^{2}+\varphi(y)\}$ is achieved at some unique point

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, banach-spaces

I'm doing Ex 3.32.5 in Brezis's book of *Functional Analysis*.

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a uniformly convex Banach space. Let $\varphi: E \to (-\infty,+\infty]$ be a proper convex l.s.c. Then for every $x \in E$ and every integer $n \geq 1$,
> $$
> \inf _{y \in E}\left\{n |x-y|^{2}+\varphi(y)\right\}
> $$
> is achieved at some unique point, denoted by $y_{n}$.

My first step is to show that the map $y \mapsto |x-y|^{2}+\varphi(y)$ is bounded from below. However, I can show it in a very limited setting when $E = \mathbb R$ (and possibly $E = \mathbb R^d)$. Could you please shed me some lights?

---

Let $E := \mathbb R$. We fix some $x\in E$ and $n:=1$. Then [there is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265004/the-right-tangent-of-a-convex-funtion) an affine function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, y \mapsto ay+b$ with $a,b$ constants such that $\varphi(x) = f(x)$ and $\varphi(y) \ge f(y)$ for all $y\in E$. Then
$$
|x-y|^2 + \varphi(y) \ge |x-y|^2 + ay+b =y^2+(a-2x)y+(x^2+b),
$$
which is bounded from below in $y$.

Comment: You do not need to show boundedness from below. You need to show boundedness of a infimizing sequence. Use that a lsc convex functions is bounded from below by an affine function.

Comment: @daw Could you give me some references that contain the proof of "a lsc convex functions is bounded from below by an affine function". I found [one](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9467-7_9.pdf), but the proof there uses the inner product of Hilbert space.

Comment: this should be contained in any book on convex analysis, for instance Barbu & Precupanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fix $x \in E$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. It follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416107/confusion-about-the-proof-that-every-convex-proper-l-s-c-function-is-bounded-be) theorem that there exist $a\in \mathbb R$ and $f \in E'$ such that $\varphi(y) \ge f(y)+a$ for all $y\in E$. Then
$$
n|x-y|^2 + \varphi(y) \ge n|x-y|^2 + f(y) + a \ge n|x-y|^2 - \|f\| |y| + a.
$$

Clearly, the map $g:y \mapsto n|x-y|^2 - \|f\| |y| + a$ is bounded from below. Let $(y_m)$ be the minimizing sequence. Then $(y_m)$ is bounded. If not, $g(y_m) \to +\infty$, which is a contradiction.