# Brezis' Exercise 4.10.1 and 4.10.2

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. Let $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $j:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be convex. We define
> $$
> J:L^p(\Omega) \to (-\infty,+\infty], u \mapsto \int_\Omega j \circ u.
> $$
> Prove that $J$ is convex and lower semi-continuous.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is correct?

---

**Proof** Notice that $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ and Jensen's inequality imply $J(u)$ is well-defined for every $u \in L^p(\Omega)$. Notice that $L^\infty (\Omega) \subset L^{n+1} (\Omega) \subset L^n (\Omega)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^*$.

1. $J$ is convex.

Let $t \in [0, 1]$ and $u_1, u_2 \in L^p(\Omega)$. By convexity of $j$,
$$
j (t u_1 (\omega)+(1-t)u_2(\omega)) \le tj\circ u_1 (\omega)+(1-t) j \circ u_2 (\omega)
\quad \forall \omega \in \Omega.
$$

Then
$$
\int_\Omega j \circ (tu_1+(1-t)u_2) \le t\int_\Omega j \circ u_1 +(1-t) \int_\Omega j \circ u_2.
$$

Then $J(tu_1+(1-t)u_2) \le tJ(u_1)+(1-t)J(u_2)$ and thus $J$ is convex.

2. $J$ is l.s.c.

First, we assume $j$ is non-negative. Fix $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. To prove that $J$ is l.s.c., it suffices to prove
$$
A:=\{u \in L^p(\Omega) : J(u) \le \alpha\}
$$
is closed. Let $u_n \in A$ and $u \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $L^p$. [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301365/convergence-in-mathcal-l-1-implies-mu-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence) a sub-sequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $u_{\varphi (n)} \to u$ $\mu$-a.e. Then $j \circ u_{\varphi (n)} \to j \circ u$ $\mu$-a.e. By Fatou's lemma,
$$
0 \le \int  j \circ u \le \liminf_n \int j \circ u_{\varphi (n)} \le \alpha.
$$

Hence $u \in A$. To solve the general case, we need

> [Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416107/confusion-about-the-proof-that-every-convex-proper-l-s-c-function-is-bounded-be) Any proper convex lower semi-continuous function is bounded from below by a continuous affine function.

By above **Lemma**, there are $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $j' (x) :=j(x) - ax-b \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Clearly, $j'$ is convex. Let
$$
J':L^p(\Omega) \to (-\infty,+\infty], u \mapsto \int_\Omega j' \circ u.
$$

As we have just proved above, $J'$ is l.s.c. On the other hand, $J'(u) = J(u) -a \int u \mathrm{~d} \mu-b \mu(\Omega)$. Clearly, $u \mapsto -a \int u \mathrm{~d} \mu-b \mu(\Omega)$ is continuous. Hence $J$ is l.s.c. This completes the proof.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Perhaps just  mention that $j$ is continuous (this is the case since $j$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @OliverDíaz I don't get $j$ being continuous is sufficient for what purpose. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @OliverDíaz I hope you can have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4672071/brezis-exercise-4-10-3-how-to-prove-that-u-n-is-measurable) related question.

Comment: I am not saying is sufficient, but in your application of Fatou's Lemma you implicitly use $\lim_n j(u_{k_n}))=j(u)$ which holds by continuity off $j$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz You're right!