Is every convex function the supremum of a countable family of affine functions?
Let $V$ be a separable normed space and $M$ an open convex subset of $V.$ Then $M$ has a countable dense subset $D.$ If $f$ is convex, then at every point $t$ of $D$ there is a support, namely an affine function $A$ such that $A \leq f$ on $M$ and $A(t) = f(t)$. Assume $D = (t_n)$ is an enumeration of $D$ and choose $A_n$ any support of $f$ at $t_n.$ Let $\varphi = \sup A_n,$ which is convex satisfying that $\varphi \leq f$ on $M$ and $\varphi = f$ on $D.$
Now, if $f$ were continuous (which is guaranteed if $\dim V < \infty$), then so would be $\varphi$ and by density of $D,$ we would have $f = \varphi$ on $M$ (not just on $D$).

Is continuity of $f$ essential in concluding $f = \varphi$? By that I mean, can any convex function $f:M \to \mathbf{R}$ be written as the supremum of a countable family of affine functions?


Something obvious is that one can relax the hypothesis of $V$ being a normed space by changing it into a Hausdorff TVS, and the same proof works and the same question remains, can we dispense of continuity?

Are these affine functions required to be continuous? If 'yes' then $f$ needs to be continuous somewhere to get the existence of the supporting hyperplanes. If 'no' then how to conclude $f=\phi$?

You might be interested in this recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.18650 , where a convex function is constructed with everywhere empty subdifferential.

I know that if at every point $f$ has a continuous support, then $f$ itself is continuous; I also know that if $f$ has a closed graph, $f$ is continuous. In fact, for all applications of interest, $\dim V < \infty$ where $f$ is continuous. But I was wondering if every convex function is the supremum of a countable family of affine functions (which then has to be continuous), or rather, only those convex functions that are continuous can be written in such special way.

How do you get continuity of $\varphi$ from continuity of $f$? Since $\varphi$ is a supremum of continuous functions, we get lower semicontinuity, but I do not see how continuity could be achieved.

A necessary and sufficient for a convex function $\varphi,$ defined on an open convex set $M$ of a normed space is that $\varphi$ should be upper bounded on the neighbourhood of a point of $M.$ Since $\varphi \leq f$ and $f$ is continuous, $f$ is bounded on the neighbourhood of any point of $M,$ so is $\varphi$.

This is not a complete (pun intended) answer, but too long for a comment.
If the space $V$ is complete, then every convex and lower semi-continuous function $f \colon M \to \mathbb R$ is automatically continuous. Hence, you need an incomplete space or a non-lsc function $f$.
An interesting situation is the following. Let $c_c$ be the space of finite sequences equipped with the $\ell^2$-norm. Then the function
$f \colon c_c \to \mathbb R$,
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x_n^2,
$$
is convex, lower semicontinuous, but nowhere continuous.
Note, however, that this function possesses a continuous support line at every point (which contradicts your claim in a comment).
I did not checked the details, but I could imagine that we could choose a dense subset $D$ consisting of points of the form
$$
d := \hat x + \varepsilon e_n
$$
where $\hat x$ is a rational approximation on the first $m$ components, $\varepsilon > 0$ is small and $n \in \mathbb N$ is very large.
Now, given any $x \in c_c$,
we find a $d \in D$ like above such that $x - \hat x$ is very small.
If take the supporting function at $\hat x$ and evaluate it at $x$,
we get
$$
A_{\hat x}(x)
=
f(\hat x) + f'(\hat x)(x - \hat x)
\approx
f(x) + n \varepsilon^2 - 2 n \varepsilon^2.
$$
This
is much smaller than $f(x)$ (if, in the construction of $D$, we have taken care such that $n$ is really very large).

I should have mentioned that we use completeness of $V$ in "$f$ is continous if and only if there is a(t least one) continuous support at every point" because this follows from Baire's category theorem.

We endow $V'$ with the weak-star topology. And we assume that $V'$ is separable with respect to this topology. If $V$ is separable then $V'$ seems to be weak-star separable. (Need to look for references).

Claim: Let $V$ be a normed space with $V'$ weak-star separable. Let $f: V \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ be proper, convex and lower semicontinuous.
Then $f$ is the supremum of countably many affine and continuous functions.

Then there is an affine and continuous function $g$ such that $g \le f$.
Now let
$$
A := \{ (g,a) \in V' \times \mathbb R: \ g(x) + a \le f(x) \quad \forall x\in V\}.
$$
This set is non-empty. Then
$$
f(x) = \sup_{ (g,a) \in A} g(x) + a .
$$
(These two claims need Hahn-Banach, but do not need completeness of the space.)
Since $V'$ is separable, also  $V' \times \mathbb R$ is separable.
Let $B \subseteq A$ a countable and dense subset.
Define
$$
\phi(x):= \sup_{ (g,a) \in B} g(x) + a .
$$
Clearly $\phi \le f$.
Take $x\in V$ and $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $(g,a) \in A$ such that
$$
f(x) \le g(x) + a + \epsilon.
$$
Due to the weak-star separability, there is $(h,b) \in B$ such that
$ (g-h)(x) < \frac\epsilon 2$ and $|a-b|<\frac\epsilon 2$.
Then
$$
\begin{split}
f(x) &\le g(x) + a + \epsilon \\
&\le h(x) + b + (g(x) - h(x)) + (a-b) + \epsilon\\
&\le h(x) + b + 2 \epsilon \le \phi(x) + 2\epsilon.
\end{split}$$
Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this proves $f\le \phi$ and $f=\phi$.

Here is a counterexample in the non-separable case. Let $V = \ell^2(\mathbb R)$, i.e., the set of functions $x:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $x(i)\ne0$ only for at most countably many $i$, and $\sum_{i\in \mathbb R} x(i)^2 < \infty$.
With the norm $\|x\|_{\ell^2(\mathbb R)} := \left( \sum_{i\in \mathbb R} x(i)^2 \right)^{1/2}$ this is a non-separable Hilbert space.
We identify $V =V'$.
Now define the convex and continuous function
$$
f(u):= \sum_{i\in \mathbb R} x(i)^2 .
$$
Let
$$
\phi(x):= \sup_{ (g,a) \in B} \langle g, x\rangle + a 
$$
as above with $B \subset V \times \mathbb R$ countable such that for all $(g,a)\in B$ we have  $\langle g, x\rangle + a \le f(x)$ for all $x\in V$. Note that $x=0$ implies $a\le 0$ for $(g,a) \in B$.
Let
$$
I := \{ i \in \mathbb R: \ \exists (g,a) \in B : g(i) \ne 0\}.
$$
Such $g\in V$ is only non-zero on a countable set, hence $I$ is countable. Then there is $j\in  \mathbb R\setminus I$ such that $g(j) =0 $ for all $g$ with $(g,a)\in B$.
Define $x = \chi_{ \{j\}} \in \ell^2(\mathbb R)$. Then $f(x) =1$ and $\phi(x) = \sup_{(g,a)\in B}a \le 0$.

One should emphasize that you show that the dense subset $D$ can be chosen such that $\varphi = f$. In my understanding of the question, $D$ is already given and cannot be adapted to the structure of $f$.

@gerw Maybe I answered the question in the title. The key idea in my answer is to chose a dense subset in the dual space not a dense subset of $M$ or $V$.

@gerw $D$ can depend on $f,$ and I expect it to depend on $f$ indeed.

@daw separability of $V$ is assumed; I would suspect the result is false in non-separable case as one could consider an infinite non-denumerable family of independent vectors, take the projection onto them (as a Hamel basis, say), and then consider the supremum of such collection. Something like ought to create a counterexample in the non-separable case.

Added a counterexample in a non-separable Hilbert space.

The proof works for weak-star separability. So separable $V$ are covered.

I don't understand the first line where you claim the existence of a continuous $g$ such that $g \leq f.$ I know that we can assume, after two translations, that $f(0) = 0$ and then there is a supporting linear form $g$ such that $g \leq f$ everywhere. I suppose you are using lowersemicontinuity of $f$ to deduce continuity of $g$ (indeed, suffices to show $g$ is upper or lower bounded in a neighbourhood of the origin) but I don't see how it follows...

see this result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416107/confusion-about-the-proof-that-every-convex-proper-l-s-c-function-is-bounded-be
